# Is the subset of a set and its negation equivalent to the empty set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

ie. is $\subseteq A \cap \bar A$ equivalent to $\emptyset$ ?

Just thinking about it logically, this seems to make sense to me, but I couldn't find any similar questions when I searched so I'm still unsure. I apologize if this is a poor question but I'm a beginner when it comes to set theory.

Comment: Question is worded a bit weirdly, implying that there is "**the** subset" of something. Anyway, there is only one subset of the intersection of a set and its complement, namely the empty set. So yes, $A \cap \bar{A} = \emptyset$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question essentially asks whether the statement $$B\subseteq A\cap \bar A$$ implies $$B=\Phi $$

The answer is yes because the empty set is a subset of every set and nothing belongs to both the set and its complement.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is whether  the following assertion holds:

> Given a set $A$, a set $B$ satisfies the condition $B\subset A\cap A^\complement$ if and only if $B=\emptyset$.

Then, yes, that is true.